# Are all the cards in High Caliber Ops supposed to be combined with the base set?

Tags: shadowrun-crossfire, high-caliber-ops

I don't see any rules mentioning how to integrate the cards, so the obvious default seems to be to shuffle them all together, but half of the black market cards in the expansion are basics.  It seems like a heavy weighting towards diluting towards basic cards because of this.  Is there some different way we're supposed to combine these cards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are supposed to combine all cards in their respective decks with the exception of extra basic black market cards which go back in the box. The black market is supposed to have only nonbasic cards. The game is significantly harder with the basics in the dack so this might improve your winrate. :)